# how to append two dynamic string into one string in react native

Tags: react-native

I'm new in react native .I want to append dynamic two strings into one common string how can i do this?

Please fine below code

```
var commonHtml = 'my name is %s from %s';
var a ='ravi';
var b = 'chennai';
```

expected output:

'my name is ravi from chennai'

Comment: try this `var commonHtml = \`my name is {a} is from {b}\`;`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is this feature called [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) in javascript that allows you to do that. So your code would be like this:

```js
var a ='ravi';
var b = 'chennai';
var commonHtml = `my name is ${a} from ${b}`;

console.log(commonHtml); // output: 'my name is ravi from chennai'
```

> **EDIT**: Changed the erroneous variable name

Comment: Running the code snippet through an error.
But it's a correct answer ( just don't forget to use ` instead of ' )

Comment: PS: try not to use inappropriate variable names,though i have up vote cause of correct answer.